# main filtering caps in freshly fixed stereo equipment: values any good?

Tags: capacitor

[image]I have tested the main filtering caps in my stereo equipment that i just fixed, are those values any good?
C1 from left to C4 right side caps.
Those caps are made in 1979.
On the top of the capacitor its a bit started to extend also at the bottom of some caps, its started leaking at the safety pressure valve (Like C1)(or whatever its called :D ) At the edge of the capacitor, its glue only.
Is it worth to put those caps back?
Electronic component tester doesn't say what is the frequency.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

Comment: ... and post the values as text and not a photo. Also. although not majorly important, what frequency was the ESR measured at by the meter?

Comment: That's well within the typical tolerance for  large electrolytics. I'd replace the leaking one though.

Comment: Where is the electrolyte leakage? The brown stuff is just glue you know. If the tops are bulging it is a sign of failure.

Comment: @Justme There is a preasure valve between the + and - legs, C1 is starting to leak there

Comment: @Greenonline Electronic component tester doesn't say what is the frequency.